# which way can I understand the past event

Tags: grammar

I played football at 5 o'clock yesterday.
does it mean:

1. I **started** to play football at 5 o'clock yesterday.
2. I **finished** playing football at 5 o'clock yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

> I played football at 5 o'clock yesterday. does it mean: 1- I started
> to play football at 5 o'clock yesterday. 2- I finished playing
> football at 5 o'clock yesterday.

The sentence is not particularly idiomatic. If anything it means "I started to play ..." it definitely does *not* mean "I finished playing ..."

---

Normally we would say:

"I started football at 5 ..."

and

"I played football until 5 ..."

---

You could also say:

"I was playing football at 5 ..."

This would mean that your game was in progress at 5, but would say nothing about when it started or finished.

---

---

**In response to a comment**

> "I played football until 5" or "I was playing football until 5" or "I
> had been playing football until 5" which one is correct?

They are all grammatically correct. Whether the verb tense is correct depends on the context.

**For example**

1.
*Father: What did you do yesterday afternoon son while I was at work?*

*Son: I played football until 5, then I came home.*

2.
*Police: The murder was committed at 5pm. We think you did it.*

*Suspect: No, I have an alibi. I was playing football until 5 so it
couldn't have been me.*

3.
*Wife: Do you remember how we first met?*

*Husband: Yes, I remember it very well. I had been playing football
until 5 that afternoon. Afterwards I was heading home when we
accidentally bumped into each other ...*

Comment: "I played football until 5" or "I was playing football until 5" or "I had been playing football until 5" which one is correct?

Comment: @Waleed Gh - I have added to  the answer.